# .NET 3.5 CF on Windows CE Platform Builder 6

Tags: compact-framework, windows-ce, platform-builder

I downloaded Platform Builder for Windows CE 6.0 and upgraded to R2 and R3. I am not able to see .NET CF 3.5 in the "Applications and Service Development" pane of the OS Design Wizard. I am able to see 2.0 only.

Please help. All the information on the internet says that 3.5 should be available if R3 is installed.

Answer (score 0):

What QFE's have you installed?  Just installing PB probably won't get you there.  Install the [2009 Cumulative Rollup](http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/en/details.aspx?FamilyID=0e929f91-a379-4277-80d5-a66e3b821ba1&displaylang=en) and you will get it.